# Extract whole SQL Server database to CSV file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, csv

It is possible to extract all tables and rows of each table with one query or software in microsoft sql server?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using the Import/Export Wizard.  (Right Click database -> Tasks -> Import/Export Wizard)

Or for greater control you could use SSIS.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is correct but if this is something you want to script and do regularly, this might get you started:

```
exec sp_msforeachtable 'exec xp_cmdshell ''bcp database_name.? out c:\?.csv -S server_name -T -c -t ","'''
```

Caution... This uses an undocumented stored procedure and assumes that xp_cmdshell is enabled and that the xp_xmdshell account has rights to sql server.